# Wrong estimation of gas while contract deployment

Tags: solidity, web3js, tokens, erc-20

I have a smart contract:

```
pragma solidity 0.5.3;

import "./ERC20.sol";

contract Transfer {

  ERC20 private erc20iface;
  address private _owner;

  modifier validOwner() {
    require(msg.sender == _owner);
    _;
  }

  constructor() public {
    _owner = msg.sender;
  }

  function () external payable {}

  function transferTo(address[] memory receivers, uint[] memory amounts, address token) {
    //Some code uses ERC20 methods/or simple transfers with .call()
    }
 }
```

When I try to deploy the contract in Remix
it shows the `transaction cost` = `424652` gas.
However when I try to estimate gas limit with web3 .estimateGas()

```
const contractData = {
      data: '0x123',
      arguments: []
    };

    const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(CONTRACT_ABI).deploy(
      contractData
    );
    const gasLimit = await contract.estimateGas();
```

I get gasLimit = 409652
And when I try to deploy, I receive an `error: Out of gas`

But if I use the amount of gas from Remix (`424652`) it works fine.

What can be the reason of such differences (15000 gas, like if .estimateGas is missing ERC20 import)? And how to estimate the `gasLimit` with `.estimateGas()` correctly?

Comment: Different compiler perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you aren't including the creator address in the `estimateGas()` version, it defaults to the 0x0 address. So in the constructor, it sets `_owner = 0x0`, which only costs 5k. The Remix version uses a non-zero creator though, which causes a 20k cost. That accounts for the 15k savings in `estimateGas()`

Comment: I think I'd do some clarification work on "causing the 15k savings over the Remix version which uses a non-zero creator address" (the contextual grammar here is rather unclear IMO).

Comment: haha i'd noticed I worded it poorly, was editing it while you commented

Comment: I actually copied it after the change, and it still isn't very clear (though a little clearer than the previous version). Why would a 5k cost lead to a 15k savings? You mean, setting to 0 costs 5k while setting to non-zero costs 20k? The math would be a whole lot more obvious if you phrased it this way.

Comment: does the current version make more sense? feel free to edit if you think you could make it clearer

Comment: Yes, though probably also worth mentioning that by "creator" you mean "the deployer account", and also, you could add `{from: "0x0"}` to the `estimateGas` call, so that this user will understand where he or she should have specified that "creator".